# Quarkus Hibernate/Panache NativeQuery with Multiple Row Inserts

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, quarkus, quarkus-panache

I'm trying to create some type of update endpoint that when you hit it does an insert from one table to another table. Basically it takes from a table named `funds` which was `fundId`, `reportingfrequency` and `country`. IT retains the `fundIds` and for the value it gets a List of Dates that are a result of a join with a Postgres stored procedure/function. Here is an example of the SQL query in it's entirety. So ideally if there are 100 rows in the table it would insert all 100 rows with an array of dates into the `due_dates` table.

```
INSERT INTO due_dates (fund_id, listdate)
SELECT fundid,
     (
        SELECT array_agg(weekdays::date)
        FROM generate_series(date'2021-01-01', date'2021-12-31', interval '1' day) as t(weekdays)
        LEFT JOIN holidays.poland(2021, 2021) f ON (weekdays = f.datestamp)
        WHERE f.datestamp IS NULL 
        AND extract(dow from weekdays) BETWEEN 1 AND 5
     )
FROM funds
WHERE reportingfrequency = 'Daily';
```

Now my issue is I'm not sure how to... programmatically do this so that depending on the rows from the `funds` table... I'm not sure how to grab the `country` field from the row to do a specific stored procedure call. For instance if a single row has `Poland` in it's `country` field then it would ideally call `holidays.poland(2021, 2021)`... and if the country was USA it would call `holidays.usa(2021, 2021)`. Here's how my current NativeQuery.

```
entityManager.createNativeQuery("INSERT INTO due_dates (fund_id, listdate)" +
                                        "SELECT fundid," +
                                            "(" +
                                            "SELECT array_agg(weekdays::date)" +
                                            "FROM generate_series(date'2021-01-01', date'2021-12-31', interval '1' day) as t(weekdays)" +
                                            "LEFT JOIN holidays." + country + "(" + year + "," + year + ") f ON (weekdays = f.datestamp)" +
                                            "WHERE f.datestamp IS NULL" + 
                                            "AND extract(dow from weekdays) BETWEEN 1 AND 5" +
                                            ")" +
                                        "FROM funds" +
                                        "WHERE reportingfrequency = 'Daily'; ")
        .executeUpdate();
```

Is there something I need to do to tweak the original SQL statement before I can achieve what I want to do?

Comment: Seems like a design problem to me. How about changing the store procedure to take in country as an parameter? `holidays('poland', 2021, 2021)`